# Почему pdoSitemap не выводит ресурс коллекции и ее дочерние ресурсы?

Tags: php, modx, php7

Создал **sitemap.xml** с помощью pdoSitemap как в инструкции itchief.ru/lessons/modx-revo/modx-revo-creating-sitemap-xml

Сам ресурс коллекции опубликован и его дочерние ресурсы тоже. Но pdoSitemap упорно игнорирует их вывод.

```
[[!pdoSitemap? 
    &checkPermissions=`list`
    &resources=`1,3,6`
]]
```

Ресурсы 1 и 3 — это обычные документы — они в xml-файл выводятся, а вот ресурс с ID 6 и его дочерние ресурсы — игнорируется.

В чём может быть дело?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался! На вывод в **pdoSitemap** влияет опция ресурса «Доступен для поиска». Если ресурс для поиска не доступен, то он не выводится в sitemap.